# Workaround to use a non ascii character to replace an accent character to a non accent

Tags: python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

I would like to use another way to change characters with accent to non-accented. For example: change an "é" to "e" ...etc

I have to stay in python 2.7

I use a rather special interpreter that does not take non-ascii characters in my code. 
With the following error displayed: "code contains non-ascii characters"

How could I get around this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import re

chaine = '/lâllôlélûl/fdfd58'
accent = ['é', 'è', 'ê', 'à', 'ù', 'û', 'ç', 'ô', 'î', 'ï', 'â']
no_accent = ['e', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'u', 'u', 'c', 'o', 'i', 'i', 'a']



for i in xrange(len(accent)):
    chaine = chaine.replace(accent[i], no_accent[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Source Code Encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding)

By default, Python source files are treated as encoded in ASCII. To declare an encoding other than the default one, a special comment line should be added as the first line of the file. The syntax is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

**Another way**

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import unicodedata

chaine = 'çàlaïù'

str_input = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(chaine, 'utf-8'))
print str_input.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
print chaine
```

[image]

Comment: I've tested it, but it doesn't work. 

In fact, I would like to transform my "accent" list into non-ascii characters. Because I think the interpreter doesn't really like this type of character. 

How could I change that?

Comment: I changed my answer, use "cp1252"

Comment: After that, i have this : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 0
SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string

Comment: @Taylor08 please remove your answer and edit the main question. I added the screenshot, it works.